# Algorithm: Creating an outage table

Tags: algorithm, date, datetime

I created this device which sends a point to my webserver. My web server stores a Point instance which has the attributes `created_at` to reflect the point's creation time. My device consistently sends a request to my server at a 180s interval.

Now I want to see the periods of time my device has experienced outages in the last 7 days.

As an example, let's pretend it's August 3rt (08/03). I can query my Points table for points up to the last 3 days sorted by created_at

```
Points = [ point(name=p1, created_at="08/01 00:00:00"), 
           point(name=p2, created_at="08/01 00:03:00"), 
           point(name=p3, created_at="08/01 00:06:00"),
           point(name=p4, created_at="08/01 00:20:00"), 
           point(name=p5, created_at="08/03 00:01:00"),
     ... ]
```

I would like to write an algorithm that can list out the following outages:

```
outages = { 
  "08/01": [ "00:06:00-00:20:00", "00:20:00-23:59:59" ], 
  "08/02": [ "00:00:00-23:59:59" ],
  "08/03": [ "00:00:00-00:01:00" ],
}
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?